# Send/receive infinite loop with SocketServer - Python - ConnectionAbortedError

Tags: python, client-server, handle, socketserver

I am trying to use socketserver to create a simple server to send images to a client with TCP.
First I send a catalogue to the client and then it responds with a request.

In the handle of my server, I have this loop :

```
class MainHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
def handle(self):

        while 1:
            try:
            # Sending the catalogue
                # Using my methods to get my catalogue with a HTTP header
            response = self.server.genHTTPRequest(self.server.init.catalogue)
            self.request.sendall(response.encode())

            # Response of the client
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).decode()
            if self.data:
                print("Data received : {}".format(self.data))

        except:
            print("transmission error")
            break;
```

In the main I use this line to create my server (it's in an other file) :

```
mainServer = MainServer.MainServer((init.adresse, int(init.port)), MainServer.MainHandler)
```

When I launch this program, the client connect successfully and receive the catalogue but it sends back only some data and the program jump in the exception of the try/catch. Without the try/catch, I got this error :

```
self.data = self.request.recv(1024).decode()
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I don't understand what is the problem, maybe a synchronization missing or may I need to use threads ?

Thank you for your help

(I am using python 3.3)

Comment: I think the connection is being reset. Try wiresharking the line (loopback). You can also try disabling your firewall or anti-viruses.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have fixed the problem. It was because the client sent wrong information and there was a problem with the recv and the client cut the connection.

By the way, I decided to use SocketServer for this project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be because of `sendall(response.encode())` and this `self.request.recv(1024).decode()` has been done in the same socket and it could lead to `ConnectionAbortedError`.

You need to read all the data from the socket before putting other data into the socket. Like flushing of data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472876/why-is-host-aborting-connection this post would be much helpful