# Client side ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] when waiting for response s.recv(4096)

Tags: python, sockets

Simple server-client python 3.x application running locally (both on the same machine) sending simple messages back-and-forth.

I am not sure why but ever so often when waiting on a response from the server my client gets the following error and then terminates

```
pickledResponse = s.recv(4096);
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

What could cause this? Could it be a timeout or something? Looking for a way to avoid this and seeing as it is a local program for a school project really anything is fine :)

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472876/why-is-host-aborting-connection

Comment: Show some code please.